# mysql malformed packer error when grouping

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to select and group two fields, one is varchar, one integer. My sql returns
error 2027 malformed packet error. The select statement is :
   select * from student  group by student_no,month

It have error when used month. Originally month is an integer. Then I change month column to varchar. The error still exist. However, if I group other fields not include month , it is ok.

So, what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of MySQL server are you running? Have you tried this with the MySQL command line client?  This sounds like a bug in the server or client library version. Does SELECT * without the group by work? If so, it should not be a problem with the table or data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you changed the data type of that column with existing data. However, what previously was an integer is now a string which doesn't work out. Better you repopulate the month field in all records.